# Where does the console.log output go when I deploy aws lambda locally?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sam

If I use aws lambda on the cloud, console.log output is routed to cloudwatch. But where does it go if I use `sam local start-api`?
Because I can't find it in cloudwatch

Comment: I think it also goes to the stdout (your command prompt/terminal/console)

Comment: @petey Really..?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [sam local start-api](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-local-start-api.html) documentation shows that you can control the log file that runtime logs are sent to with the command line option:

```
-l, --log-file filename
```

Comment: didn't notice it at first since it had some prefixin front of the output